# Accumulation point of open interval in real numbers

Tags: general-topology

In book General Topology by Kelley it is stated:
If $A=(0,1)$ is a subset of topological space $(\Bbb R,\tau)$,
then every point in closed interval $[0,1]$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

I understand that in topological space, accumulation points of $[0,1]\subset \Bbb R$ are $0$ and $1$.
But how is entire closed interval a set of accumulation points of the same open interval?

Comment: every point in $[0,1]$ is an [accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $[0,1]$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$

Comment: It doesn't hold for any topology defined on $\mathbb{R}$. For example if a topology is induced by a metric $d(x,y) = |x-y| + |sgn(x) - sgn(y)|$ then $0$ is not an accumulation (limit) point of any set. Did you mean an euclidean topology in your question?

Comment: @MatthewW I guess it is usual topology, since the book is introduction to topology for graduates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The limit points of an open interval (open set)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2573976/the-limit-points-of-an-open-interval-open-set)

Comment: @MatthewW, yes it does. thank you.